# Spring 3.2.2 property-placeholder not working

Tags: java, spring, properties, configuration

I work with Spring 3.2.2 . I want to use db.properties file for DB parameters

db.properties

```
db.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test
db.user=test
db.password=test
```

spring configuration

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:db.properties"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${db.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${db.user}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
</bean>
```

but I have error

```
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [${db.driver}]
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Your properties file is at the top level of the classpath, right?

Comment: How are yo loading this xml file? Please add the full stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

Try to define you property file in spring as:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <value>classpath:db.properties</value>
        </property>
</bean>
```

and than access it in a same way as you did.

Comment: I use Mybatis and when I used mybatis-spring 1.0.1 it is working but when I used 1.1.1 version is did not works